# Regex for single space

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a file which is delimited by multiple spaces. The problem I have is that the first field can contain a single space. How can I match this with a regex?

Eg:

```
Name           Other Data    Other Data 2 
Bob Smith      XX1           0101010101
John Doe       XX2           0101010101
Bob Doe        XX3           0101010101
John Smith     XX4           0101010101
```

Can I split these lines into three fields with a regex, splitting by a space but allowing for the single space in the first field?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a regex. Since they are separated by spaces you could just read 15 characters at a time to get each column and then strip out the whitespace to get the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi the following regex should work

```
(\w*\s\w*)\s+\w{2}\d\s+\d*
```

Comment: Your answer led me to the correct regex, thanks. The final regex I used was `(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)$`

Answer (score 5):

This would work:

Pattern:

```
(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*?)[ ]{2,}(.*)
```

Replacement:

```
+$1+ -$2- *$3*
```

`$1` contains the first column, `$2` the second and `$3` the third one.

Example:
http://regexr.com?32tbt

Answer (score 3):

You could split at two or more spaces:

```
[ ]{2,}
```

But you are probably better off, determining the lengths of the captures of this regular expression:

```
(Name[ ]+)(Other Data[ ]+)
```

And then to use a simple substring method that slices your lines into portions of the same length.

So in your case the first capture would be 15 characters long, the second 14 and the column would have 13 (but the last one doesn't really matter, which is why it isn't actually captured). Then you take the first 15, the next 14 and the remaining characters of every line and `trim` each one (remove trailing whitespace).

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest is to use a regex that matches two or more spaces.

```
/  +/
```

Which breaks down as... delimiter (`/`) followed by a space () followed by another space one or more times (+) followed by the end delimiter (`/` in my example, but is language specific).

So simply put, use regex to match space, then one or more spaces as a means to split your string.

Comment: The `/` are not part of the regex and are only used as delimiters in a certain number of languages. Also, for readability, I would highly recommend writing every literal space in a regex as `[ ]`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with this kind of files, the best approach is to get a substring based on where your required information is and then trim it. I see your file contains 16 chars before the second field, you can get a substring of length 16 from the beginning which will contain your desired text. You should trim it to get only the text you need without the spaces.

If the spacing pattern you posted is consistent (if it won't change among different files of this kind) you have also another problem: what happens to longer names?

```
Name           Other Data
Johnny AppleseeXX1
TutankamonfirstXX2
```

if you really want to use a regex, be sure to avoid those corner cases.